# Looping a Python Script Based on Line Count

Tags: python, bash, loops

I have a python script that basically does some stuff on a file and results in a shorter file.  I want the script to continue running on each subsequent output file until the output file and the most recent input file have the same number of lines.

The python script works like this:

```
python Joiner.py input.txt output.txt
```

I want to create a BASH script that will run something like this:

```
while [outputfilelines -lt inputfilelines]
do

python Joiner.py inputfile.txt outputfile.txt

done
```

Where each output file then becomes the input file for the next loop.  I've tried a few different things but I can't seem to get it to work correctly.  I can't figure out how to keep one file in the loop and spit out the other one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much brute force and ignorance:

```
I_FILE="input.txt"
O_FILE="output.txt"

old=$(wc -l <"$I_FILE")
while python Joiner.py "$I_FILE" "$O_FILE"
      new=$(wc -l < "$O_FILE")
      mv "$O_FILE" "$I_FILE"
      [ $new != $old ]
do
    old=$new
done
```

The `while` condition evaluates four commands — the `python` command, the `new=` line count assignment, the move command and the `[ $new != $old ]` test which controls the loop (it is the test that counts).  If the counts are different, then record the new count as the old count and repeat. Not many people know that you can run multiple commands like this in the condition part of a shell `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
IN=input.txt
OUT=output.txt

touch $OUT
while [ ! $(wc -l < $IN) -eq $(wc -l < $OUT) ]; do
        python Joiner.py $IN $OUT
        mv $OUT $IN
done
```

Comment: Why not just wc -l $IN?

Comment: Why not just `wc -l < $IN`?  The reason why you don't use `wc -l $IN` (without I/O redirection) is that `wc` includes the file name in the output.  With input redirection, it leaves out the file name.  The `cat` is [UUOC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) — Useless Use of `cat`.  Also, why the `touch out`?  Should that be `touch $OUT`?  The `! a -eq b` notation is more complex than `a -ne b`, too.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler. The reason for not using -ne is that I have never learned it as ! x -eq y is just natural for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the contents also become identical, you can use diff:

```
while ! diff "$IN" "$OUT"; do
    python Joiner.py "$IN" "$OUT"
    mv "$OUT" "$IN"
done
```